# Jupyter notebook command not recognized in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

I recently installed `miniconda` as I am following a course on ML and data science.

Then I created a virtual environment name `env` with the help of `conda` assistant that `miniconda` provides.
And install all my library in that `env`.
Also installed Jupyter notebook, and commands are like.

To install Jupyter note book in  my virtual environment name env

```
(C:\Users\username\Desktop\my-project-1\env)
C:\Users\username\Desktop\my-project-1> conda install jupyter
```

To run the Jupyter notebook inside my env i use

```
(C:\Users\username\Desktop\my-project-1\env)
C:\Users\username\Desktop\my-project-1>jupyter notebook
```

And this command was working fine. But I don't know how today when I wrote the same command it is showing me.

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable programme or batch file.
```

[image]

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but I'm a bit confused after looking at your image. What is your environment? Because I see no text above "base". What `conda` command did you use to create the `env`? Normally activation is done via `conda activate <environment_name>`

Comment: Yup i used ```conda activate <environment path>```

Comment: I use ```conda env list``` to see my env list.. And use one of the environment and run the command ```jupyter notebook``` but it shows that error.. I have only one environment..

Comment: I think you have two environment. You have `base` and that other one that has no name.

Comment: ```base``` is the default enviroment..  And the ```env``` is one that I have created..

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here (I'll change my answer depending on new information), but if it was installed and worked, then what probably happened is that you aren't in the activated `conda` environment. However, I'm a bit confused by your environment list as the name of the `env` environment is not provided (I don't see test above "base"). It should be something simple/short, like "my_test_env". It should not be a path to a folder.

If you properly activated the right environment then `conda info --envs` will list your environments and there should be a "*" indicating which environment you're using in that terminal.

Also, try `conda list` to see what is included and check for `jupyter`.